# Is it enough to check ergodicity for intervals?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, measurable-functions

Let $T:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be a Lebesgue measurable map which preserves the Lebesgue measure (indicated here by $m(\cdot)$).

Suppose that
$m(T(I))= 1$ for every nonempty $T$-invariant *interval* $I\subset [0,1]$. Does this imply that $T$ is ergodic?

My try: given a measurable set $A$ and $\epsilon>0$, there is an open-interval cover $\{U_n\}_n$ of $A$ such that $|\sum_n m(U_n)-m(A)|<\epsilon$. Then applying the condition to every $U_n$, if thery are invariant, you get the result, but $A$ could be invariant without all $U_n$ being such...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Note that the statement works for an equivalent condition for ergodicity: $T$ is ergodic iff for any measurable $A,B$: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mu(A\cap T^{-k}(B))=\mu(A)\mu(B)$ iff for any $A,B\in\mathcal{S}$ the same limit holds, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the generating semi-algebra of subintervals ($\mathcal{S}$ can be any generating semi-algebra). For details see Einsiedler-Ward p.27 and Exr.2.7.3 and Exr.2.7.4 on pp.52-53 (the latter exercise is essentially what you are asking).

Comment: @AlpUzman This is really useful. I'll accept it if you write it as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful; though it's not quite an answer to what you asked; Amadeus's answer answers your question more specifically it seems to me.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept it. But thank you anyway, you indicated me a result I can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't. Take for instance the rotation by $\frac{1}{2}$, that is,

$$
T(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+\frac{1}{2}, \ \text{if} \ x < \frac{1}{2}\\
x-\frac{1}{2}, \ \text{if} \ x \geq \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}
$$

it can be viewed as a rotation if we identify the endpoints of $[0,1]$ to turn it into a circle. By definition any invariant set must contain full orbits, that is, if $A$ is invariant and $x \in A$, then $T(x)$ is in $A$.

Suppose now  that $I$ is an invariant interval and take $c$ its infimum. If $c \geq \frac{1}{2}$, then $T(x) = c - \frac{1}{2} \in I$, which contradicts the definition of infimum. Therefore $c < \frac{1}{2}$ and since $I$ is an interval and $c,c+\frac{1}{2} \in I$, then $\left[c,c+\frac{1}{2}\right] \subset I$. If $c = 0$, then
$$\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right] \subset I \implies [0,1) \subset I \implies m(I) = 1$$
and if $c >0$, then
$$\frac{1}{2} \in \left[c,c+\frac{1}{2}\right] \subset I \implies T\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0 \in I$$
which contradicts the fact that $c = \inf I$. Therefore $c = 0$ and $m(I) = 1$, which shows that $m$ is "interval ergodic" with respect to $T$.

But $m$ is not truly ergodic with respect to $T$, indeed, take $J$ a closed small interval contained in $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $A = J \cup T(J)$ which is an invariant set with $0< m(A) < 1$.